# Does Clang support conditional macro expansion?

Tags: macros, clang

By `Conditional Macro Expansion`, I means something like this:

```
XXX(_arg) => AAA(_arg), if _arg > 0
XXX(_arg) => BBB(_arg), otherwise
```

To be more specific, AAA and BBB are not functions but are `attribute specifiers`—`__attribute__ ((attribute-list))`, so runtime branching does not work.

Is is possible to write macros like this? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that it is obvious that you can write:

```
#define XXX(arg) ((arg) > 0) ? AAA(arg) : BBB(arg))
```

This is the simple way to do it.  If `arg` is a compile-time constant, you will get only one of the two possible function calls in the code.  If you want to try for an alternative, investigate the [Boost Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/libs/preprocessor) package, and  in particular [`IF`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/if.html) and [`IIF`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/iif.html).  It works with C as well as C++.

(I renamed `_arg` to `arg` to avoid collisions with names reserved to the implementation.  I'm not sure it actually matters in this context, but I'd steer clear of names starting with an underscore.)

Comment: `_arg` is ok, I think.  It's only identifiers that with two underscores or an underscore and a capital letter that are in the danger zone, IIRC.

Comment: I think it probably isn't a problem here — and said as much — but I'm rather cautious about such things (having been bitten too often in times past).  The standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers) says: _All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.
— All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces._ Again, it is probably OK this time, but it is easier to break bad habits when they're newly formed.

Comment: I just updated the question to be more specific. Runtime branching does not work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The usual trick in this case is to use token-pasting in a way that makes your macros sort of "polymorphic". For example:

```
#define IFtrue(a,b) a
#define IFfalse(a,b) b
#define IF(x,a,b) IF##x(a,b)

IF(true, int, double) IF(false, foo(), main()) { }
```

Unfortunately, this works only if your "condition" is literally the word `true` or the word `false`; it doesn't work for things like `a > 0`.

What is the exact problem you're trying to solve? There's probably a better approach.